# Kubernetes https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have just setup a kubernetes cluster on my raspberrypis (3 in total) and am getting this error when trying to pull a docker image from a public repo:

```
Failed to pull image "docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.2.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have only found webpages which tell you to use a image pull secret but since it is a public repo im kinda confused... At work we didn't have to use a secret for public images.

This is the service that i am trying to deploy.

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo1
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        args:
        - "-text=echo1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5678
```

But it doesn't make a difference on what service i want to deploy even the ingress-nginx doesn't work:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.34.1/deploy/static/provider/do/deploy.yaml
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's trying to pull this image `docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.2.2.` So I don't think the piece of code you show is relevant.  Could be that you try to install the enterprise version of the ningx ingress, where the repo is private, and you are not allowed to pull. Where did you get the command from?

Comment: Although, I can see it here. https://hub.docker.com/layers/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen/v1.2.2/images/sha256-05108bacbf03ab6de72327f2564f188488960266f857befac07a5e1f802bf70c?context=explore

Comment: Ah maybe be that because you are on PI, there is no ARM version available. But then the error should be different I think.

Comment: Can you pull any image? like `docker run hello-world`?

Comment: I can docker pull and run any image. I got the command from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

Comment: when using microk8s the docker images were running correctly...

Comment: I stoped using microk8s ecause i couldnt use the automatic cert-manager the challenge faild because i called my page (which was accesablie) and didnt find the challenge url. But thats a different issue link -> kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.16.1/cert-manager.yaml

Comment: so it must be specific to your Kubernetes installation. What version have you installed? Can you share output of `kubectl get all -n kube-system` maybe some of those pods have issues like core-dns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm strongly convinced that @The Fool is right about raspberry and arm package. The image you are trying to use is not compatible with your device.

Try:

```
k8s.gcr.io/echoserver-arm:1.8
```

or:

```
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=echoserver-arm&type=image
```

Comment: okay, thanks. can i change anything in my config or sould i rather just use microk8s?